# Why this code works for SQL Server Express but *not* SQL Server CE?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, sql-server-ce, nullreferenceexception

I get a `NullReferenceException` when my target provider is SQL Server CE, but with SQL Server Express it works. I get the exception on the `return...` when I'm trying to access the `Comments`. Model is very simple and it can be inferred from the code. Thanks for any help! I'm using Entity Framework code-first 4.3 and SQL Server CE 4.0 by the way.

- using the same code with SQL Server Express as provider = runs fine
- using the same code with SQL Server CE as provider = exception error

In addition, I have no problems with SQL Server CE. It works on my machine and I have done single-table operations with Entity Framework code-first and even asp.net authorization. I have never done any nested addition/deletion like this on related entities though so I'm curious as to why this doesn't work..

```
            db.Persons.Add(new Person()
            {
                FullName = "JC Viray",
                Comments = new List<Comment>(){
                         new Comment(){CommentContent="Hello!"},
                         new Comment(){CommentContent="World!"}
            }
            });

            db.SaveChanges();

            return db.Persons.FirstOrDefault().Comments.FirstOrDefault().CommentContent;
```

What stumps me also is that in SQL Server Express, if I examine the data, the comments are there.

In SQL Server CE, only the `Persons` table has data while the `Comments` table is empty.

EDIT:

If it helps, here is the model:

```
    public class Person
{
    [Key]
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}

public class Comment
{
    [Key]
    public int CommentId { get; set; }
    public string CommentContent { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Person")]
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What version of SQL Server Compact are you using?

Comment: If you debug with breakpoint can you see if Persons contains anything? Cause Persons.FirstOrDefault() can return NULL if nothing is found which can lead to NullReference. Samething with Comments.FirstOrDefault(). Without having the code under hands, it's hard to see but you can check it when debugging. Good luck.

Comment: I installed it on my project from NUGET and on my machine, I installed it from the official page, so the latest one.. 4.0.8852.1

Comment: Have you tried checking out relationships, db - clean up, start from scratch - check your migrations, do `Update-Database -Script` to see what you have?

Comment: @PatrickDesjardins -- well, I do run the same code when I change my provider to SQL Express and it works. It doesn't return null and I get the exact results I want. I have also checked it on breakpoint and it does contain data *but* it seems to not persist in SQLCE

Comment: SQL Server CE database is a file, right? If you copy the comments for SQL Express to your CE database? This extension can help you: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0e313dfd-be80-4afb-b5e9-6e74d369f7a1

Comment: @AndreiDrynov: yes, the SQLCE db file does exist. Person is persisted, but not the Comments.... in SQL Express, both Person and Comments are persisted... I think it may have to do with my code perhaps? Maybe I should not use anonymous functions for SQL CE?? not sure.. ill try to not use anonymous functions here... or maybe enter the id directly.. let me see...

Comment: I'll check too. Just a note: in code first the primary key is assumed by convention. If it is ID or Id or the entity name + Id/ID (like PersonId), there is not need to use [Key] attribute. It will be the primary key by default.

Comment: @AndreiDrynov -- actually I finally figured it out after all these headaches..

Comment: If the table Comments has no data, the FirstOrDefault method will throw the exception: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482.aspx. They suggest using DefaultIfEmpty. So the question is why your table is empty? How do you persist table Comments?

Comment: that SQL CE db was not in synced. It's wierd because I did not get any error about not being in synced as I usually get when I use SQL Express...

Comment: I guess what was wrong was that SQL CE exception details are a lot too vague than using SQL Express... Null/DataException (SQLCE) vs Model has changed (SQL Express)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that: **SQL CE error details are a lot more vague than when using SQL Server Express as provider** therefore the confusion and the vague direction.

**SQLCE Exception details is something like:**

*NullException*

**SQLExpress Exception details is something like:**

*The model backing the 'MyContext' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=238269).*

The solution is: **to sync** the models by adding this code:

`Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<MyContext>());`

Comment: Check http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=27290 for a way to initialize SQL Server 4.0 compact. You could also consider Database Migrations if your models keep changing http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/02/09/ef-4-3-automatic-migrations-walkthrough.aspx

Comment: @AndreiDrynov Thank you for the information! Definitely are a great help :)